Angular material dialogue "cdkFocusInitial" not focusing properly for button
I am using Angular material dialogue for Confirm submit, with two buttons one for yes and other for cancel.
Here "cdkFocusInitial" was used for yes button. The button was focusing for initial submit. But when we press the cancel button and again submitted, the yes button was not focusing, i.e. "cdkFocusInitial" is not working here.
The image shows the initial submit.

The image below shows the submit after clicking the cancel button.

Below my dialogue component.html
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Confirm Submit</h2>
<mat-dialog-actions>
        <button mat-button   mat-raised-button cdkFocusInitial  mat-dialog-close="true" style="margin-right: 5px;">Yes</button>
        <button mat-button  mat-raised-button mat-dialog-close="false">Cancel</button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>

The dialogue open code in other submit component
 openDialog(){
let dialogpopupref=this.matdialog.open(DialogpopupComponent);
dialogpopupref.afterClosed().subscribe(result=>{
 console.log("dialog result is" +result);
  if(result=="true"){
    console.log("in true");
 }
});
  }

Please someone help in solving this issue. Whenever I submit, the confirm dialogue must open with "yes" button focused.

@NarenMurali unfortunately, that StackBlitz link is broken. But I can confirm that with the given code the issue is not reproducible.

@Reegan please share stackblitz where the issue happens, issue not reproducible on stackblitz
